# Windows 10 shared folder - Does the username matter at all?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, credentials

I have shared a folder on my LAN and restricted access to one user:

`user: mymachine\owner
password: secret`

When I'm trying to access this folder over network by another computer with both different username and password, the access is correctly denied, for example:

`user: different_machine\someone
password: admin
--> access denied`

But on my laptop where I have another username, but the same password as on `mymachine\owner`, the access is granted, for example:

`user: different_machine\someone
password: secret
--> access granted`
I don't even need to enter any password.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour? Why is that? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Are any of these machines on the same Windows domain?  Windows can also be set to remember credentials, which you can clear at Control Panel->User Accounts->Manage your credentials.  Find the share name and remove it.  Log out / log in , or remove the mapped drive using 'net use'

Comment: Silly me. Yes, the credentials were stored. I had to delete them 2 times and restart my machine 3 times until they really had been removed. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherHostage not sure if you saw the OP's response but you've got a solution waiting to be posted as an answer. Ping me for an up vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows can remember credentials, which can make remote access confusing, especially when the same username is used on multiple standalone PCs.

In this instance, the solution was to clear out the credentials at Control Panel->User Accounts->Manage your credentials. Find the share name and remove it. Log out / log in , or remove the mapped drive using 'net use' before testing it.

Comment: As in my case, this might need a few tries and restarts..